# Lookup ID in XML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a simple ajax call in JavaScript which returns an ID, I then need to make another ajax call to fetch an XML file which contains all of the ID's with the relevant descriptive string as part of the XML.

The ID's description comes back in this format:

```
<Category>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Descriptor>Accounts</Descriptor>
</Category>
<Category>
  <Id>2</Id>
  <Descriptor>Marketing</Descriptor>
</Category>
<Category>
  <Id>3</Id>
  <Descriptor>HR</Descriptor>
</Category>
etc...
```

How can I lookup the ID value against this XML and return the Descriptor string using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery you could do:

```
var xml = $.ajax({......}); //your xml
var numb = $.ajax({......}); //returns 1,2 or 3 etc...

var descriptor = $('id', xml).filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == numb; //filter elements based on text in the id tag
}).siblings('Descriptor').text();
```

jQuery will treat it as html, but it seems to work all the same.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/tM9RN/2/)

Comment: Slick +1. I'm almost tempted to -1 because of the terrible readability, though.

Comment: Improved the readability, as for some reason I'm getting downvoted ?

Comment: You should also explain what you're doing in your `return` statement.

Comment: Sure, it's a filter to get only the element that contains the number you are looking for, there's really no need for `each()` or `find()` for this, as the selector is a shortcut for `find()`, and the filter does the same as iterating with `each()` in a cleaner way !

Answer (score 1):

Something like this function should work:

```
function searchXmlForId(id) {
    var searchDescriptor = "";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "your/xml/file.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('Category').each(function(){
                if (curId == $(this).find('Id').text()) return $(this).find('Descriptor').text();
            });   
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

And then you call it like this:

```
var myDescriptorFromId = searchXmlForId(1);

>> "Accounts"
```

Comment: +1 because your solution is better than regex here for the robustness and readability, and speed probably isn't an issue here. I'm leaving my regex answer posted though for completeness sake. But I recommend the OP choose this over mine.

Comment: One suggestion though: Instead of extracting the descriptor from every category, I'd put that inside the check, and I'd eliminate the local variables. Both changes for speed. And I don't think it would really hurt readability much. I.e.: `if (curId == $(this).find('Id').text()) return $(this).find('Descriptor').text();`

Comment: Yep, I could do that, and in fact I will. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

People are going to jump down my throat for suggesting regex here, but I contest that it's probably the fastest solution (for the haters, I'm *not* parsing xml here, and have no intention to -- I'm simply extracting information via a text pattern):

```
var matches = xml.match(new RegExp('<Id>' + id + '<\\/Id>[\\s\\S]*?<Descriptor>(.*?)</Descriptor>', 'i'))
var description = matches ? matches[1] : null;
```

Comment: Oh, geez. +1 because of the cleverness, but I really am tempted to jump down your throat.